# Jsoup select elements from dropdown menu

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I have been trying to access a specific element from a dropdown menu on a Steam leaderboard page. Is there a good way to access a specific 'option value'? I have tried the following code and it isn't grabbing any value (debugger shows levelName as "").

```
String url = "http://steamcommunity.com/stats/592300/leaderboards/1900835";
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
String levelName = document.select("div#leaderHeader > option:contains(1900822)").val();
System.out.println(levelName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your code:

- `:contains` doesn't check attributes, but text generated by element. If you want to find `<option value="1900822">someText</option>` using `value="1900822"` then you can use `[attr=value]` selector like `option[value=1900822]` (without quotes)
- you used `parent > child` but `<option ...>` is child of `<select ...>` element, not `<div id="leaderHeader">`. This div is its ancestor, but it is not parent, so remove that `>`
- I am not sure what you are trying to do with `val()` method here, but I am guessing you want to use `text()`.

So you probably want:

```
String levelName = document.select("div#leaderHeader option[value=1900822]").text();
```

Just notice that there are some [non-breaking spaces](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) `&nbsp;` in result. You may want to replace them with simple spaces and after that trim leading and trailing ones.

```
levelName = levelName.replace((char)160,' ').trim();
```